# how to schedule thingsboard export of device data in csv report

Tags: csv, export, schedule, thingsboard

#### see my answer below on how I solved this using python

Using cloud PE edition maker level and my client needs a report schedule of device data.
I realise that the user can manually do a table export, but this is not adequate for the client.
I've noted past questions which have have asked similar but I can't see a full answer to this issue.  Is there any new advice on this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844153/export-telemetry-data-of-a-device-in-thingsboard

Would Trendz ($) provide this function?

I've also seen that the REST API could be used, but that just adds another level of complexity of handling JSON to produce the report.  Not really a solution to the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I've now created a python script to produce a csv file report from Thingsboard and below outlining the key concepts needed to achieve this.  I found the TB documentation a bit light so hope that some of this detail is of help to others.

The process I used was to make a REST API call using the TB python library.  This worked very well.

But before cracking on with python, use the swagger interface to test your login and data calls:

https://thingsboard.cloud/swagger-ui/
(for the cloud instance of TB)

make sure to login at the Authorize button before making the REST calls
It is useful to do a first test using a simple method, e.g. device-controller, GET device id:
https://thingsboard.cloud/swagger-ui/#/device-controller/getDeviceByIdUsingGET

This checks that your login and the desired device id are working ok.
By the way, the device id is that listed at the admin dashboard under Entities->Devices->[select device of interest]->[copy device id]

As I want data from a particular device for a timeseries, use the method under the section telemetry-controller, GET timeseries data:
https://thingsboard.cloud/swagger-ui/#/telemetry-controller/getTimeseriesUsingGET

Pay attention that the method asks for the entityType (DEVICE) and also the entityID (what you copied from device id above).  You also need to provide the parameter key(s) for the telemetry you want.  If you're not sure of the exact key names, go back to the admin dashboard as above and select the Latest Telemetry tab to view the keys that your device is using.

Using this in swagger will check that you can access the device and pull the data from the database for a time period that you want.  It's better to do this first than later also having doubts about the python code operation.

Now onto Python:
First, refer to the TB documentation:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/python-rest-client/
install the TB python library to your computer/server with:
pip3 install tb-rest-client

Now start writing a script.  The code lines below are NOT a fully working python script, but the key lines you'll need.  Recommend starting simple to make sure the login and GET methods are working for you.

```
# library modules you'll likely need are
from tb_rest_client.rest_client_pe import *
from tb_rest_client.rest import ApiException
import logging
import json
import datetime
import time
import csv

# provide the TB url to use
url = 'https://thingsboard.cloud'

# create a TB object for the code
rest_client = RestClientPE(base_url=url)
try:
    result = rest_client.login(username='your_username', password='your_password')
    current_user = rest_client.get_user()
    print('login result: {}'.format(current_user))
except ApiException as e:
    print('login error: {}'.format(e))

# with a successful login now get data
# annoyed note:  the device id is NOT the entity ID!!
# have to provide python object that states the entity type and id
# refer to the swagger page for what is expected by each method
entity_id = EntityId(entity_type='DEVICE', id=TB_creds['device_id'])

# make an object for the parameter keys you want to get
keys = "key1,key2,key3"   # note: do NOT put spaces between the keys!
start_ts = 1704153600000   # an epoch value in ms to start from e.g. Jan 2 2024
finish_ts = 1704240000000   # an epoch value in ms to finish at e.g. Jan 3 2024

# now use the above with the TB rest api to get timeseries for the selected device, telemetry keys and defined time period
result_js = rest_client.get_timeseries(entity_id, keys, start_ts, finish_ts)
```

Some other observations to note:
There appears to be a limit on number of lines of data that can be retrieved in one call.  That is, 100 time points can be downloaded.  More than this is truncated.
Multiple calls may be made at sequential time blocks to overcome the 100 limit.   But you will end up with multiple sets of data to parse in order to create a desired output format.
Data is returned in order of most recent first.  This can be a bit unexpected if you want data in earliest time first.
Each parameter key is ordered separately, meaning that the resulting data is ordered by key then by timestamp.  If you - as I did - want to list by time order then key value then it is necessary to parse the returned data and create a new object that is ordered by timestamp and they key value.

I won't go into detail on how to parse the data block to create an object that can be saved as csv.  But let's now assume you have a data dict object that consists of timestamp followed by a list of telemetry data for each key.

How to write a csv file in python:

```
  file_name = 'some_file_name.csv'
    with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    try:
        file_obj = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        file_obj.writerow(["Thingsboard report", time.strftime('%d/%b/%Y %X', start.timetuple())])  # give the report a title line
        file_obj.writerow(["device id", TB_creds['device_id']])   # put device id in the file
        file_obj.writerow(['ts'] + key_list)  # write column headings for ts and key items
        for ts_point, values in data_obj.items():
            file_line = [ts_point] + values
            file_obj.writerow(file_line)
     except:
        print('unable to make csv file')
```

Feedback or comment on this is welcome and I'll try to answer questions if possible.  An upvote is appreciated if you like this answer.